# Printing hexadecimal values to console in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char array[10];

    for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
    {
        array[i] = 'a' + i;
    }

    char* test = array;

    printf("%x\n", test);
    cout << hex << test << endl;

}
```

The output for this is:

```
bffff94e
abcdefghijN???
```

Why is it not printing the same thing?

Comment: If you want to print a pointer, you should use `%p` with `printf()`, `%x` is for an unsigned hexadecimal integer. Like `%x`, `std::hex` doesn't work as you expect with pointers, it aims to be use with integral numerical values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cout << hex << test << endl;
```

It prints the string, not the address. It is because there is an overload of `operator<<` which takes `char const*` as argument and this overload treats the argument as string.

If you want to print the address, cast the argument to `void*` so that *other* overload of `operator<<` will be invoked which will print the address.

```
cout << hex << static_cast<void*>(test) << endl;
```

will print the address, in hexadecimal format.

Note that `hex` stream-manipulator is not needed here, as the address will be printed in hexadecimal format anway. So

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(test) << endl;
```

is enough.

Comment: Would `&test` instead of `(void *) test` not work just as well (and look a bit less daunting to a [perhaps] newer programmer)?
(Forgive me if I am wrong here; I don't work in C++ too much.)

Comment: @Nawaz Wrong. `&test` prints something else. Your example uses an *array*, not a *pointer*, which is why it works but OP uses a pointer. Also, please get rid of these C-style casts. We have a broad consensus that they shouldn’t be used, which makes them even more harmful in teaching material (= here).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Ohh.. you're right. (now please remove the downvote :D)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: c-style casts are good here. It is short and cute. It's application cannot harm here.

Comment: The answer is good, except for the C-style cast (which is why I don't upvote either). A lot of newcomers might just copy-paste blindly such answers and we will never get rid of these ambiguous C-style cast in bigger codebases.

Comment: Just for the record, I don't have anything against C style casts in this specific case (but generally, I restrict them to numeric values, and ban them on pointers---accepting them for `(void*)` in an output statement is an exception.

Comment: Note that the response is wrong on several counts.  For starters, and most importantly, you really should point out that the original has several cases of undefined behavior.  And secondly, there's no guarantee that outputting a pointer will result in hex.  I've worked on machines where it was octal, and on one of the most widespread machines a few years back, it had the format `XXXX:XXXX` (where XXXX _was_ hexadecimal).  And the `hex` modifier isn't required to have any effect on a `void*`; you could get octal even with it.

Answer (score 6):

Because your program has undefined behavior.  And because you ask it to
print different things.

Your invocation of `printf` is illegal, and results in undefined
behavior (and is a good example of why you should never use `printf`).
Your format specifier says to extract an `unsigned int` from the 
argument list, and output that in hexadecimal.  Passing it anything but
an `unsigned int` is undefined behavior.  As it happens, given the way
varargs are generally implemented, if you're on a machine where
`unsigned`s and pointers have the same size, you'll probably output the
value of the pointer, treating its bits as if it were an `unsigned`.
Other behaviors are certainly possible, however.  (If I'm not mistaken,
g++ will warn about this construct; it's also possible that on some
platforms, it will crash.)

In the case of `std::cout`, you're passig it a `char*`.  By definition,
the `char*` is treated as a '\0' string, *not* as a pointer (and
certainly not as an `unsigned int`).  And again, you have undefined
behavior, since your `char*` doesn't point to a '\0' terminated string;
you never put a '\0' at the end.  (This probably explains the `"N???"`
you see at the end of your output.  But again, undefined behavior is,
well, undefined.  The code could just as easily have crashed.)

Finally, you're using both `printf` and `std::cout`; the results are not
really specified unless you do a flush of the stream between the two.
(In practice, if you're outputting to an interactive device, the flush
should occur when you output the `'\n'` character.  If you redirect the
output to a file, however, you're likely to get something different.)

It's not clear what you want.  If you want to output the address of
`array`, it would be:

```
printf( "%p\n", test );
std::cout << static_cast<void*>( test ) << std::endl;
```

If you want to output the string you've generated, then append a '\0' to
the end of it (without overflowing the buffer), and then:

```
printf( "%s\n", test );
std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to make "hex"; there is no such thing as
a hex representation of a string, and the representation of a pointer is
implementation defined, and not required to take into account any
formatting parameters in iostream.  (Typically, on most modern machines,
it will be hex.  But I've worked on more than a few where it would be
octal, and at least one where it wouldn't be just a number, regardless
of the base.)  If you want a hex dump of `array`, you'll have to loop,
outputting each value as an `unsigned` in hex:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i ) {
    printf( "%x", static_cast<unsigned char>( test[i] ) );
}
printf( "\n" );
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::hex, std::ios::basefield );
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i ) {
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>( static_cast<unsigned char>( test[i] ) );
}
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::dec, std::ios::basefield );
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Finally: a word about the casts: plain `char` may be either signed or
unsigned; if it is signed, converting it to an `int` or an
`unsigned`, might produce either a negative value (`int`) or a very
large positive value (`unsigned`).  Thus, the first conversion to
`unsigned char`, which guarantees a result in the range `[0, UINT_MAX]`.
Second, of course, we have to convert the `unsigned char` to `unsigned`:

- in the case of `printf`, because we would otherwise have undefined
  behavior, but the conversion is implicit, since passing an `unsigned
  char` as a vararg automatically promotes it to `unsigned`; and
- in the case `std::cout`, because the rules are that any character
  type be output as a character, not as a numerical value (and since the
  type is used here in function overload resolution, and is not being
  passed to a vararg or an `unsigned`, there is no implicit conversion).

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation pointing out all the issues in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

`test` itself is a pointer, i.e. it stores an address. Your `printf` statement prints the hexadecimal value of that address.

The `cout <<` statement then prints the entire string, because the `std::hex` manipulator does not affect the way strings are printed. It only affects the way integers are printed.

What you can do is

1. Loop through the characters of the array
2. Convert each to an integer and print using the `std::hex` manipulator

That would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
  std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(array[i]) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

`cout << HEX <<`
can't be used to a char* to print a hex char string,
but you can use it for int ,double,float,etc.

And, as you second print, why the string has some garbled strings is that you haven't gived
a '\n' to the string which means the end of string